# PHP + MySQL - Form cannot update multiples tables at a time

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having bad time to update multiple tables from a form. I've done the query and checked for errors using (or die), but it seems that there are no errors in my MySQL codes. I can update the main table's data, but I can't update the other table. I'm suspecting that my form fields have some problem. This is my form codes :

```
<?php

$sql= "SELECT * FROM client WHERE resID=".$_GET["resID"];
$rs = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

$sqlM= "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE resID=".$_GET["resID"];
$rsM = mysql_query($sqlM) or die($sqlM."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

$i = 0;


echo '<table width="50%">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>ID</td>';
echo '<td>Name</td>';
echo '<td>Edit</td>';
echo '</tr>';






echo "<form name='form_update' method='post' action='client_admin_post.php'>\n";


$f=mysql_fetch_array($rs);echo '<tr>';
echo "<td>Res ID :</td>";
echo "<td>{$f['resID']}<input type='hidden' name='resID' value='{$f['resID']}' /></td>";
echo '</tr>';
++$i;

echo '<tr>';
echo "<td>Restaurant Name :</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' size='40' name='resName' value='{$f['resName']}' /></td>";
echo '</tr>';
++$i;


while ($fM = mysql_fetch_array($rsM)) {

echo '<tr>';
echo "<td>Menu :</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' size='40' name='mname[$i]' value='{$fM['name']}' /></td>";
echo "<td>{$fM['id']}<input type='hidden' name='mid[$i]' value='{$fM['id']}' /></td>";
echo '</tr>';
++$i;
}


echo '<tr>';
echo "<td><input type='submit' value='submit' /></td>";
echo '</tr>';
echo "</form>";
echo '</table>';

?>
```

This is my POST codes :

```
<?php


        //session_start();
        include_once("connection.php");

        $resID= $_POST["resID"];
        $resName= $_POST["resName"];

            $sql = "UPDATE client ".
           "SET resName = '$resName' ".
           "WHERE resID = '$resID' " ;

       mysql_query($sql) or die ('query failed:' . mysql_error());

    $size = count($_POST['mname']);

    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $size) {
    $name= $_POST['mname'][$i];
    $id = $_POST['mid'][$i];

    $sqlM = "UPDATE menu SET name = '$name' WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1";
    mysql_query($sqlM) or die ("Error in query: $sqlM");
    echo "$name<br /><br /><em>Updated!</em><br /><br />";
    ++$i;
    }

    ?>
```

As you guys know, one restaurant got many menus. I can edit the main restaurant info, but I can't edit the menus. Please help me. Really appreciate your help. Thanks :D

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Put `print_r($_POST)` in the beginning of your POST code and check what data you're actually receiving.

Comment: Got 2 menus. I got '1' for each menus

Comment: Discovered some hints maybe, when I delete the first table form codes, the second table works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ++$i at least twice before outputing it as $mname index. So $_POST['mname'] would have indices 2 .. count_of_rows+1. Your while() ignores this fact and counts 0 .. size.

If you had all warnings turned on (as you should) you would get a warning indicating that invalid index 0 is used on line starting "$name= $_POST..." and you would have been able to figure out from there.

Comment: Thank you very much. How could I correct it? Sorry for asking too much but I'm still a beginner.

Comment: Discovered some hints maybe, when I delete the first table form codes, the second table works